Controlling for regression to the mean in nonparametric survey response data - pre-post design - difference between groups
I have 920 pre-post responses to 5-point Likert-scale questions evaluating the impact of an educational intervention. I wish to test whether outcomes (change = post - pre) differed across different groups (e.g. by discipline). The data is not normally distributed.
I am confident that the data set does not suffer from history, maturation, or test-effects.  However, regression to the mean is clearly an issue when comparing between groups.  e.g. discipline 1 has lower pre test scores than discipline 2 (and more responses at extreme of 1), thus will be more prone to RTM effects in the post-test...leading to significant risk of misinterpreting the data.
As a single group design (practical constraints), I do not have a control group to compare to.  The data is nonparametric. I am struggling to find a straightforward way to evaluate (a) the extent of the RTM effect and (b) to avoid or minimise the RTM effect when testing for differences between groups.  Here are my specific 2 questions:
Q1: For parametric data, the extent of the RTM effect can be estimated from (1-r).  Is it valid to do this using the Spearman's rank order correlation coefficient? (this varies from 0.352 to 0.579 across the six repeated Qs)
Q2: Binning data based on an independent variable and excluding extreme responses have been identified as approaches to avoid or minimise RTM effects. I don't have an appropriate independent variable.  Can I instead analyse by groups defined by pre-test response? e.g. for each (1 to 5) pre-test response, test for differences in change by group of interest (e.g. discipline) OR exclude extreme pre-test scores (1 or 5), or select median pre-test score (e.g. 3) and test for differences in change by group of interest?  Logically this feels like it would eliminate any RTM effects...
Please note that by looking at all of these things, I am pretty confident that there is only 1 significant difference between groups (between extracurricular and embedded interventions) where this difference is in the opposite direction to the RTM effect...
Many thanks in advance

The response is ordinal (5-point Likert scale) variable, so you should consider using ordinal regression. (As an aside question -- do ordinal variables exhibit regression to the mean?) Instead of looking at change scores (which might not even be a valid construct for ordinal variables), use the pre-score as a baseline covariate: post_score ~ pre_score + other covariates.

Many thanks dipetkov - not withstanding whether or not ordinal variables can regress to the mean - mine clearly do ;-)  - with strong negative correlations (Spearman's rank-order) between pre-training response and change in response across all questions.  It's not clear to me that ordinal regression would circumvent this issue...(I am no statistician!)  Do you have a view on whether or not testing the data (for differences) using ONLY responses with the pre-training median is a valid approach?  My data set is large enough to do this and maintain reasonable group size

I don't think the best you can do is to assume that your outcome is just a like a numeric variable, with perhaps a bit of loss in precision. Your outcome is ordinal and there are methods developed for outcomes like that.

See also Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs. Though you don't have a control, so I suspect you'll be limited in what you can learn from this data.
